# Enviar dados do Arduino para o Android (sensor ultrassonico)

Tags: android, arduino

Fiz esse código para receber dados de um sensor ultrassônico num celular `Android`. Após passar o aplicativo para o celular e o código para o Arduíno, ele só consegue conectar, mas não mostra os dados da distância do sensor. Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

```js
//Activity principal que realiza a conexão e mostra os dados do sensor

package com.example.sensor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.example.appenthernet.R;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
  //Handler é parte da estrutura do sistema Android para gerenciar threads. Um manipulador de objeto recebe mensagens e executa o código para 
 //lidar com as mensagens. Normalmente, você cria um manipulador para um novo tópico, mas você também pode criar um manipulador que está conectado
 //a uma linha existente. Quando você conecta um manipulador para o seu segmento interface do usuário, o código que manipula mensagens é executado 
 //no segmento interface do usuário.
 //Ou seja, é a estrutura que manipula as mensagens recebidas por bluetooth pelo ceular
 Handler bluetoothIn;

   final int handlerState = 0;           
   private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
   private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
   private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
   private OutputStream outStream = null;
   
   private static final int SolicitaAtivaçao = 1;
   
   private static final int SolicitaConexao = 2;

   //Entrada das informações para fazer a interação entre o celular e o módulo bluetooth
   private BluetoothAdapter meuBluetooth = null;
   
   // SPP UUID service - isso deve funcionar para a maioria dos dispositivos
   private static final UUID MEU_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
   
   // String para o endereço MAC
   //quando usa lista de dispositivos, se não colocar igual a null da erro
   private static String MAC = null;
 
 TextView textView1, textViewMedida, textViewString;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  textViewMedida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMedida);
  textViewString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewString);
  
  //obtém o adaptador local bluetooth
  meuBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  
  //Verifica se o didpositivo tem bluetooth
    if(meuBluetooth == null){
     //Se não tiver, a mensagem abaixo será mostrada e o programa será encerrado
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seu dispositivo não possui bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     finish();
     return;
    }
    
    //Se o bluetooth não estivver ativado, será solicitada a ativação do mesmo 
    //Através do intent, que inicia uma nova ação
    if(!meuBluetooth.isEnabled()){
     Intent solicita = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);//Cria o intent
     startActivityForResult(solicita,SolicitaAtivaçao);//Starta o intent   
    }  
  
  
     bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
         public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
             if (msg.what == handlerState) {          //se a mensagem é o que queremos,
              String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes de conexão thread
                 recDataString.append(readMessage);              //Pega os dados doa sensores até a string '~'
                 int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                       // que determina o final de linha
                 if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           
                     String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extrai a string
                     textViewString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);             
                     int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();       //Pega o tamanho dos dados recebidos
                     textView1.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));
                     
                     if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')        //se ele começa com # sabemos que é o que estamos procurando
                     {
                      String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);             //obtem o valor do sensor entre índices 1-5                 

                      textViewMedida.setText(" Sensor 0 Voltage = " + sensor0 + "cm"); //coloca o valor recebido no textview
 
                     }
                     recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());      //limpa as strings 
                    // strIncom =" ";
                     dataInPrint = " ";
                 }            
             }
         }
     };
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  switch(requestCode){
  
  case SolicitaAtivaçao:
   if(resultCode ==Activity.RESULT_OK)//Se o bluetooth for ligado, a mensagem abaixo será mostrada
   {                                   //E o progrma continuará sendo executado
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O BLUETOOTH FOI LIGADO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }else//Se o bluetooth não foi ativado, a mensagem abaixo será mostrada e o programa será fechado
   {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O BLUETOOTH NÃO FOI LIGADO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
   }
   break;
  
  case SolicitaConexao:
   if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){    
    MAC = data.getExtras().getString(ListadeDispositivos.EnderecoMAC);
    
    //Para se ter um bluetoothdevice é necessário uilizar o BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(string)
    //Que representa um endereço Mac conhecido, que já foi apresentado no início
    BluetoothDevice device = meuBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(MAC);    
    try{
     //A função device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MEU_UUID) abre m conexão 
     //Entre o dispositivo e o módulo
     btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MEU_UUID);
     //É iniciada a saída d dados do dispositivo
     btSocket.connect(); 
     
     //Se der tudo certo na hora da conexão, irá aparecer a tela do controle
     if(btSocket!=null){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A CONEXÃO FOI BEM SUCEDIDA!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    }catch(IOException e){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERRO AO FAZER CONEXÃO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    
   }else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falha ao obter o endereço MAC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  break;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.Conectar) {
   
   conectar();
   
   return true;
  }
  if (id ==R.id.Desconectar){
   
   if(btSocket !=null){
   
   desconectar();
   }else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "O módulo bluetooth não está conectado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 
  //Método que faz o envio de dados, ou seja, envia os caracteres 
  public void dadosEnvio (String data){
    
   try{
    //Permite a saída de dados a partir de um socket
    outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
   }catch(IOException e ){}
   String mensagem = data;
   byte[] msgBuffer = mensagem.getBytes();//Array de bytes que armazena a informação da string 
   try{
    //Envia a mensagem para o módulo
    outStream.write(msgBuffer);
   }catch(IOException e ){}
    }
  
 //Definição da função conectar
 public void conectar(){  
  Intent abreLista = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListadeDispositivos.class);
  startActivityForResult(abreLista, SolicitaConexao);  
 }
 
 //Definição da função desconectar
 public void desconectar(){
  try{
   btSocket.close();//Fecha a conexão
   btSocket = null;//E a conexão volta a ser nula
         
  }catch(IOException e){
   
  }
 }
}
```

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```css
//Programa do arduino

#include <Ultrasonic.h>

//Define os pinos TRIGGER e ECHO do sensor ultrassonico
#define PINO_TRIGGER 13
#define PINO_ECHO 10

//Inicializa o sensor ultrassonico
Ultrasonic sensor(PINO_TRIGGER, PINO_ECHO);

float cmMsec;//variável que irá armazenar os dados do sensor

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  valores_para_envio();

  long microsec = sensor.timing();// contabiliza o tempo necessário para o sinal ir e voltar

  cmMsec = sensor.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);//calcula a distância em centímetros

  delay(1000);
}

void valores_para_envio() {

  //indica que a comunicação foi iniciada
  Serial.print("#");
  //Envia o valor medido pelo sensor
  Serial.print(cmMsec);
  //Usado para identificar o fim da trasmissão
  Serial.print('~');
  Serial.println();
  delay(10);

}
```

```
//Activity para a lista de dispositivos 

package com.example.sensor;

import java.util.Set;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListadeDispositivos extends ListActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter meuBluetooth;
    static String  EnderecoMAC = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayBluetooth = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        //obtem o bluetooth local do dispositivo
        meuBluetooth= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //Pega os dispositivos paredaos 
        Set<BluetoothDevice> dispositivospareados = meuBluetooth.getBondedDevices();

        //Se o tamanho dos dispositivos for maior que zero, serão adicionados os dispositivos na lista
        if(dispositivospareados.size()>0){
            for (BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice : dispositivospareados) {
                String nome = bluetoothDevice.getName();
                String mac = bluetoothDevice.getAddress();

                ArrayBluetooth.add(nome +"\n"+mac);

            }
        }

        setListAdapter(ArrayBluetooth);     
    }

    //Método de click na lista
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //Obtém todos os dados do item que foi clicado
        String InfoGeral = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();

        //Retira o endereço MAC que são os ultimos 17 caracteres da informação
        String mac = InfoGeral.substring(InfoGeral.length()-17);

        Intent retornaMac = new Intent();
        retornaMac.putExtra(EnderecoMAC, mac);

        //Atribui o resultado como OK e fecha a lista
        setResult(RESULT_OK,retornaMac);
        finish();
    }




}
```

Comment: Se você usar o Serial Monitor da própria IDE do Arduino configurado com velocidade 9600 você consegue receber os dados do Arduino? Outra sugestão: Existe um programa pra Android (não me lembro o nome agora) que permite que você conecte em dispositivos Bluetooth e receba/envie dados. Já testei um Arduino com um adaptador Bluetooth dessa maneira e funcionou. Enfim, o que estou propondo é que você primeiro teste o Arduino + Adatapdor Bluetooth em algo que você tenha certeza que funcione. Se tudo der certo, aí você começa a avaliar o seu programa.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, pelo que pude perceber, você não está lendo dados recebidos, já que você não faz em lugar nenhum isso:

`InputStream in = bluetoothkSocket.getInputStream();`

O que você precisa fazer é criar outra thread que ficará em loop esperando envios do seu sensor no Arduino, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
// Faça isso a partir do momento que o seu bluetooth socket for diferente de null
    // Que é quando você tem a conexão
    final InputStream in = bluetoothkSocket.getInputStream();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while (running) {
                try {
                    length = in.read(bytes);
                    // Isso supondo que a mensagem que você envia seja uma string
                    String msg = new String(bytes, 0, length);
                    // Método para atualizar a interface
                    msgReceived(msg);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Apenas a UI Thread pode atualizar a tela no android:

```
private void msgReceived(final String msg) {
        // Vai rodar na UI Thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Faça o que quiser com a msg. Atualizar um textView, por exemplo.
            }
        });
    }
```

Como dito, não esqueça que tudo isso precisa ser feito em outra Thread.

Já quanto a parte do envio da informação no Arduino, se está sendo feito corretamente, eu não sei lhe dizer.

***Edit:***

Lembrando que o método `in.read(bytes);`, é bloqueante, ou seja, ele ficará parado nesse método até que se venha uma resposta. 
Segundo a própria documentação do Java sobre o método:

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is
>   detected, or an exception is thrown.

O que deixa mais claro a importância de utilizar outra Thread para esperar a resposta.

Comment: Como assim outra thread? Onde eu adicionaria ela?
Mais uma vez grato pela atenção!!

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Cara, não entendi.
Dá pra vc adicionar no meu código por favor?

Comment: Logo mais eu adiciono esse código no seu e já atualizo aqui.

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: o msgreceived e o running não consegui entende-los. Dá pra vc adicionar no meu codigo?